# Sometimes google analytics enhanced e-commerce transaction isn't updated

Tags: php, e-commerce, google-analytics-api

I have an issue with updating google analytics (GA) enhanced e-commerce transaction. Basically the goal is to add new item into purchased list and increase the revenue if entire transaction.

I am using HTTP POST request via the PHP script to submit initial transaction and to update existing. The url used to submit and update transaction - `https://ssl.google-analytics.com/collect` with the parameters that corresponds to Google's measurement protocol [described](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameter).

The flow works good including the either the initial submit or update transaction. But the is one strange use case.

If transaction update request sent right after initial transaction request submitted. The transaction data isn't updated in GA dashboard. By trying different time gaps between initial and the update request I have figure out that update transaction should be sent not less than 15 mins after initial one.

I am not sure that this number is reliable since it may be dependent on processing the initial request which up to servers power of google. To summarize I think the cause of this behavior is that initial transaction may not be processed yet by google and the update is sent (just an assumption). Also i couldn't find any mention about this kind of delay in any of the documentation pages provided by google.

Also I have tried the validation end point provided by API https://ssl.google-analytics.com/debug/collect to check if it shows the update request as correct. Despite the response says that transaction request is correct - transaction info isn't updated in dashboard after sending it via `.../collect` end point.

So I am looking for a information about either there a way to make sure that update will pass through.

It can be and defined time that I need to wait to submit the update request which I can rely on or a valid workaround.

In my case the time of update request isn't critical unless the difference more than weeks.

I expect transaction data to be updated in GA dashboard after submitting transaction update request. But if it submitted right after initial transaction the data isn't updated.